# How to Resolve Action Bar Activity?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, android-actionbaractivity

I am developing an app in Android Studio version 1.2.1.1. In which I use minsdk 15 and I what to use GoogleMap but When i am adding **compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'** or **compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'** in build.gradle. Then ActionBarActivity shows an error **android.support.v7.app.actionbaractivity is deprecated**.

I searched and found some suggestions to use **AppCompatActivity** instead of **ActionBarActivity**  but it does not allow me to debug the application
can anyone help me out in to resolve the error?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: @Pooja android.support.v7.app.actionbaractivity is deprecated is the warning message that generates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Then ActionBarActivity shows an error android.support.v7.app.actionbaractivity is deprecated.

That is not an error. It is a warning. It is telling you that `ActionBarActivity` is deprecated.

If you look at [the JavaDocs for `ActionBarActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html), you will see:

> This class is deprecated.
>
> Use [AppCompatActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html) instead.

So, replace `ActionBarActivity` with `AppCompatActivity`, and you will resolve the deprecation warning.

Comment: Sir when i try to use  AppComatActivity insted of ActionBarActivity, the application crashes every time.

Comment: @AmanSingh: Then use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this Or, leave it as `ActionBarActivity` for now, until you gain more experience in Android development and are in position to debug whatever problem you are experiencing.